# Titanium scrollView does not react

Tags: javascript, events, titanium

I try to implement an image in Titanium which can be rotated and scaled. I managed to make this work properly, but I want to be able to scroll the image around if it is bigger than the imageView. I tried several things including adding eventListeners and using the zIndex to bring the proper view to front but nothing helps. I also experimented with the bubbleParent function without any other result. I hope some of you got an idea how to achieve the desired behaviour.

XML:

```
<ScrollView id="imageScrollView">
    <View id="pictureView">
        <ImageView id="picture" ></ImageView>
    </View>
</ScrollView>
```

TSS:

```
"#imageScrollView": {
    top: "0",
    left: "0",
    height: "120",
    width: "47%",
    showHorizontalScrollIndicator: "true",
    showVerticalScrollIndicator: "true",
    maxZoomScale: "5",
    minZoomScale: "1",
    backgroundColor: "white",
    scrollingEnabled: "true",
    borderWidth: "1",
    zIndex: "1050"
}
"#pictureView": {
    top: "0",
    left: "0",
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%",
    bubbleParent: true
}
"#picture": {
    top: "0",
    left: "0",
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%",
    borderWidth: "3",
    borderColor: "red",
    bubbleParent: true

}
```

And my js

```
$.imageScrollView.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
    Ti.API.info("Triggered event");
});

$.pictureView.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
    Ti.API.info("Triggered event");
});
```

Comment: try it with: Ti.UI.createScrollableView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I finally managed this to work by using this module: [TiTouchImageView](http://gitt.io/component/org.iotashan.TiTouchImageView). If you have any problems importing / using it refer to my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26425325/is-a-titouchimageview-working-in-an-alloy-project-update).