# Is a TiTouchImageView working in an alloy project? [UPDATE]

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I am currently developing a titanium app for android and iOs including an imageView which should be scrollable and scalable (via a slider). I already get this to work on iOs but on Android it is really hard to achieve the scrolling behaviour. I decided to use the [TiTouchImageView](http://gitt.io/component/org.iotashan.TiTouchImageView) module but the documentation only shows how to use it in a non-Alloy project. My current code looks like this:

```
if (Ti.Platform.osname == "android") { 
    var TiTouchImageView = require('org.iotashan.TiTouchImageView');
    var androidImageView = TiTouchImageView.createView({
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        zoom: originalScaleValue,
        maxZoom: originalScaleValue*2,
        minZoom: originalScaleValue,
        image: blob,            });
        $.androidInnerImageScrollView.add(androidImageView);        
} else {    
     $.iosPicture.setImage(blob);
}
```

But is there a possibility to load this via the view.xml as an alloy component?

EDIT: I tried it using the `module` tag in alloy:

```
<ScrollView id="androidInnerImageScrollView">
    <Module module="org.iotashan.titouchimageview" id="androidPicture"></Module>
</ScrollView>
```

But I keep getting this error message:

```
Uncaught Error: Requested module not found: org.iotashan.touchimageview
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your input Arturo, but this was not the problem. I finally figured out how to use a module in an alloy project by reading the [guide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Alloy_XML_Markup). My final code looks like this:

```
<Module module="org.iotashan.TiTouchImageView" id="androidPicture"></Module>
```

Answer (score 3):

i have been using this in my project like.

## In xml

```
  <View id="windowView" module="org.iotashan.TiTouchImageView" platform="android" minZoom="0.1" maxZoom="9.5"></View>
```

## In tss

```
"#windowView":{
top: 44,
height: Ti.UI.FILL,
width: Ti.UI.FILL,
backgroundColor: "trasparent"
```

}

## In JS

```
$.windowView.image = "image path here"
```

And its working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the module reference to tiapp.xml? Any module should work on Alloy, you only need to take care of the SDK version.

Comment: That was not the problem since I was able to use it in the .js. I found the solution (see my own answer).