# Titanium on Android: OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, titanium, out-of-memory, image-resizing

At the moment I am working on an app which should resize an image in small steps. But on Android the heap grows with every action I take and finally I get the OutOfMemoryError. Please have a look at my .js file:

```
scaleValue = newScaleValue;
var resizedBlob = originalBlob.imageAsResized(originalImageWidth * parseFloat(scaleValue), originalImageHeight * parseFloat(scaleValue));
if (Ti.Platform.osname == "android") {
    $.androidPicture.setImage(resizedBlob);
    //$.androidPicture.setZoom(scaleValue);
} else {
    $.iosPicture.setImage(resizedBlob);
}
```

The iOs part works like a charm. I know that in (native) Android you have to recycle your bitmaps, is this possible in Titanium as well?

Comment: Doing bitmap operations on Titanium is the reason why I no longer use it

Comment: Since android 3.0 there is no need to recycle bitmaps, the gc does it for you. The problem is it can't if you hold on to the references. Without knowing your code I guess you are somehow holding an several references of bitmap

Comment: @for3st: Do you have any web resource where I could read something about that? And how should I remove the reference when the ImageView is defined in my alloy project's xml?

Comment: @RobinEllerkmann sry I have plenty of experience with memory leaks with bitmaps in native android but none in Titianium. But nevertheless I'll leave this here maybe it helps: https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally removed the non-native scaling function which caused the OutOfMemory Exceptions. Instead I used TiTouchImageView module which can be found [here](http://gitt.io/component/org.iotashan.TiTouchImageView). If you have any problems importing / using it refer to my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26425325/is-a-titouchimageview-working-in-an-alloy-project-update).